# Facebook Login in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated my app with Facebook,i've followed the facebook tutorial [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/). My app works fine in emulator but not in my real device. So, i've discovered that the problem occurs 'cause in my app i'm already logged in fb.
When session is opened i get this message: FbLogin would like to access your public profile and friend list.
After i pressed ok, don't return any graph object so the text is not setted..  can someone help me?

Comment: plz check ur code properly cos I've done same n I'm getting toasted username everytime when I click on Login button, even if I'm logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend signing out of Facebook on your device before/during testing your own apps.

No graph object is returned when the session is opened. You'll need to make another call, using the Request API, once the session is ready.